# How to unroll all nodes of a JSON tree in PostgreSQL?

Tags: json, postgresql, recursion, tree

Let's have a table with a jsonb column that represents a tree structure of nodes. To generate a flat list of all tree nodes, one per row, is easy to do in case of a simple tree structure using the amazing recursive CTEs:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE api_schema (id INT, content JSONB);
INSERT INTO api_schema VALUES (1, '[{"name": "A", "category": "tuple", "children": [{"name": "B", "category": "datapoint"}, {"name": "C", "category": "datapoint"}]}]');
INSERT INTO api_schema VALUES (2, '[{"name": "D", "category": "tuple", "children": [{"name": "E", "category": "tuple", "children": [{"name": "F", "category": "datapoint"}]}]}]');

WITH RECURSIVE schema_objects (id, object) AS (
  SELECT id, jsonb_array_elements(content) FROM api_schema
  UNION
  SELECT id, jsonb_array_elements(object->'children') FROM schema_objects
  WHERE object->>'category' != 'datapoint'
) SELECT * FROM schema_objects;
```

The tricky part is when more logic is required within the recursion formula. In my case, aside of the `datapoint` (no children) and `tuple` (children is a list) categories there is a `multivalue` category (children is a single node). How to make the CTE handle this case?

The naive rewrite of the CTE is such as this:

```
INSERT INTO api_schema VALUES (3, '[{"name": "D", "category": "multivalue", "children": {"name": "E", "category": "tuple", "children": [{"name": "F", "category": "datapoint"}]}}]');

WITH RECURSIVE schema_objects (id, object) AS (
  SELECT id, jsonb_array_elements(content) FROM api_schema
  UNION
  SELECT id, CASE WHEN jsonb_typeof(object->'children') = 'array'
               THEN jsonb_array_elements(object->'children')
               ELSE object->'children'
             END AS object
  FROM schema_objects
  WHERE object->>'category' != 'datapoint'
) SELECT * FROM schema_objects;
```

However, the trouble here is that this doesn't work in Postgres 10:

```
ERROR:  set-returning functions are not allowed in CASE
```

Could we make two SELECTs each covering a separate category? That isn't allowed:

```
WITH RECURSIVE schema_objects (id, object) AS (
  SELECT id, jsonb_array_elements(content) FROM api_schema
  UNION
  (SELECT id, jsonb_array_elements(object->'children') FROM schema_objects WHERE object->>'category' = 'tuple'
   UNION
   SELECT id, object->'children' FROM schema_objects WHERE object->>'category' = 'multivalue')
) SELECT * FROM schema_objects WHERE id=1;

ERROR:  recursive reference to query "schema_objects" must not appear more than once
```

An idea floating around the internet is using a CTE to factor out the CASE, but we already *are* inside a CTE, so this doesn't even compile:

```
WITH RECURSIVE schema_objects (id, object) AS (
  SELECT id, jsonb_array_elements(content) FROM api_schema
  UNION
  WITH schema_children (id, children) AS (
    SELECT CASE jsonb_typeof(object->'children') WHEN 'array' THEN object->'children' ELSE jsonb_build_array(object->'children') END AS children
    FROM schema_objects
    WHERE object->>'category' != 'datapoint'
  )
  SELECT id, jsonb_array_elements(children)
  FROM schema_children
) SELECT * FROM schema_objects WHERE id=1;
```

Postgres also suggest using a lateral FROM, but it's not clear how to compose one in a situation of a single "table".

Answer (score 0):

I found a mistake in an early attempt of mine when composing the question :). Using a subselect in FROM does the trick, rebundling non-array as an array:

```
WITH RECURSIVE schema_objects (id, object) AS (
  SELECT id, jsonb_array_elements(content) FROM api_schema

  UNION

  SELECT id, jsonb_array_elements(children)
  FROM (SELECT id, CASE jsonb_typeof(object->'children') WHEN 'array' THEN object->'children' ELSE jsonb_build_array(object->'children') END AS children
    FROM schema_objects
    WHERE object->>'category' != 'datapoint'
  ) s
) SELECT * FROM schema_objects
```

However, one general downside of this approach that's pretty huge is that this is awfully slow - with 10000 ~30-node trees, I'm looking at queries taking *minutes*.